# Run .bat file using shell() in R

Tags: r, pdf, cmd

I'm using the console of PDFSam to split and merge some PDF files. I can do this semi-automatically using .bat files, but I would like to do the whole thing in R.

This code in my .bat file works:

```
C:
cd "/Program Files/pdfsam/bin/"
run-console.bat -f "d:/delete/A_9.pdf" -o d:/delete -s BURST -overwrite split
```

But this "equivalent" code in my R shell command returns no errors, but doesn't seem to work.

```
shell('C: 
cd "/Program Files/pdfsam/bin/"
run-console.bat -f "d:/delete/A_9.pdf" -o d:/delete -s BURST -overwrite split')
```

Is there an option I'm missing in my shell command? I've tried a few of the options listed in ?shell to no avail.

I'm using windows XP and 
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Maybe `shell("c:/program files/pdfsam/bin/run-console.bat -f...`?

Comment: is `shell()` a windows only command?

Comment: Unfortunately, run-console.bat has to be run while within the bin directory (hence the cd comment).

Comment: I'm not sure if `shell()` is windows only or not, but I do know from using `traceback()` that it automatically converts to `shell.exec()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass multiple commands to shell by concatenating them by `&`, so below should work:

```
shell('C: & cd C:/Program Files/pdfsam/bin & run-console.bat -f "d:/delete/A_9.pdf" -o d:/delete -s BURST -overwrite split')
```

But as a workaround you could temporary change R working directory:

```
current.wd <- getwd()
setwd("C:/Program Files/pdfsam/bin")
shell('run-console.bat -f "d:/delete/A_9.pdf" -o d:/delete -s BURST -overwrite split')
setwd(current.wd)
```

If you do it frequent write a function:

```
shell.in.dir <- function(dir, ...) {
    current.wd <- getwd()
    on.exit(setwd(current.wd))
    setwd(dir)
    shell(...)
}

shell.in.dir("C:/Program Files/pdfsam/bin",
    'run-console.bat -f "d:/delete/A_9.pdf" -o d:/delete -s BURST -overwrite split')
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks, Marek. All three options work great!

Comment: I am trying to run a single .bat file using `shell('run-text2pdf.bat')`, however I get an error message of `'run-text2pdf.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c run-text2pdf.bat' had status 1 
2: In shell("run-text2pdf.bat") :
  'run-text2pdf.bat' execution failed with error code 1` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but you might try  `system("youBatFile.bat")` as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that (and using `shell.exec()`) but got the same result (well lack of result).