# R - Postgresql Export Data to CSV

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I'm trying to write a script in `R` to export a query from a `Postgresql` database to a `csv` file.

If I do this from `cmd` it works fine :

```
psql -U postgres
\copy (select * from clickthru.train limit 10) to 'c:\\me\\psql_test.csv' with csv header;
```

However when I try this in R it looks like it executes (no errors) but no file is generated:

```
system('psql -U postgres COPY (select * from clickthru.train limit 10;) TO "C:\\me\\psql_test.csv" with CSV')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `queryResult <- however you're running your query ` then use `write.csv(queryResult,  'c:\\me\\psql_test.csv'`

Comment: @FeargalRyan: That could work but the result set is too big to pass it to R via ODBC.  Ignore the 'limit 10' in the example.

Comment: Hey, looks like this behaviour has been encountered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393579/run-bat-file-using-shell-in-r . I think you need to concatenate your system commands with `&`

Answer (score 1):

use;

```
\copy (select * from clickthru.train limit 10) to 'c:\\me\\psql_test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here

1. Query should be passed via `-c` argument: `psql -U postgres -c '... query ...'`
2. `COPY` and `\copy` work differently. COPY operates on servers disk space, \copy operates on client disk space. If you run both on one computer, then the difference is that COPY will work as `postgres` user, and \copy as user who runs the script.
3. In your example you have extra semicolon (`;`) in query `...COPY (select * from clickthru.train limit 10;)...`